# Custom Search Suggestions Dropdown VueJS

Tags: vuejs3, focus, dropdown

Search Dropdown Focus Not Working

I'm currently working on a custom drop-down search field, attempting to enable navigation through suggestions using arrow keys. Despite verifying the code in the console and confirming that the correct element is being identified, the focus functionality isn't behaving as expected. You can find my code implementation on `[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Muaviya-Imran/pen/bGZYEJY)`

Comment: "_the focus functionality isn't behaving as expected_".  You need to explain what the expected behavior is then.  Code by itself doesn't reveal what it's _meant_ to do, only what it does.  Please also include code most relevant to the issue in the question itself.  Links to codepen without including any code in the question aren't allowed, which you seem to have found a workaround for by putting the link in an inline code block...  Review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is divs can't be focused by default.

you can get around this by adding `tabindex="0"` on your div with the id of `filter + index`.

It looks there are some issues with your `handleArrowDown` function. It's a bit convoluted and can be made much simpler if you use some refs instead.

I added `:ref="index"` to the same div I added `tabindex` to and then changed `handleArrowDown` to:

```js
handleArrowDown(event) {
      this.$refs[this.focusedChildIndex - 1][0].focus();
      this.focusedChildIndex++;
    },
```

As long as I understood what you were getting at this should solve your problem.

(more on refs and use with focus if you're interested https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_refs_focus_management)